# Is there a way to hide mlflow ui header when start the server with mlflow server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mlflow

I want to integrate mlflow ui to our website by using an iframe, but with the header hidden if possible. I found there is an environment variable setting in the source code /mlflow/server/js/components/HomeView.js:
`const headerHeight = process.env.HIDE_HEADER === 'true' ? 0 : 60;` But how can I specify this environment by running the server with `mlflow server`? I tried with `HIDE_HEADER=true mlflow server`, but this doesn't work. Or is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jason good question, those environment variables are read at build-time for the MLflow UI's Javascript assets. Since the PyPI MLflow wheel comes with pre-built Javascript assets, it's difficult to achieve your use case using a PyPI installation of `mlflow`.

However, you can build a custom MLflow wheel from source with the UI header hidden by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/branch-1.3/CONTRIBUTING.rst#building-a-distributable-artifact), replacing the `npm run build` step with `HIDE_HEADER=true npm run build` (basically, the idea is to set the desired environment variables prior to building Javascript assets via `npm run build`). You can then pip-install that wheel on the node hosting your MLflow server & launch the server via `mlflow server`.